# applescripted keybinding issue with extended keyboard's number keys

Tags: keyboard, applescript, key-binding, bindings

I've written an applescript that remaps the Switch to Desktop n commands to the extended keyboard's numbers instead of the main keyboard. I've looked up the codes and they are Key codes 82 - 92. The script runs without issue but the keystrokes are still using the builtin keyboard's numbers.

When I open System Preferences and click into the Shortcut for each command, type it using the extended keyboard's numbers it works without issue, though, confusingly, the input on the screen is the exact same.

Can anybody tell me how I'd go about remapping these commands to use the extended number keys?

Here's the applescript that i wrote to [Remap the Switch to Desktop](http://pastie.org/private/ayycbaiznbhsvz0minc5q)

Comment: I'm puzzled… you already know how to remap the keys from 'above qwerty' to the 10-key, simply change the key-command in sys prefs/keyboard. Yes, they do look identical & the defaults are the qwerty, but it's simple enough to go down the list & change them manually. Are you looking for a repeatable solution? Do you have GUI scripting enabled?

Comment: I was looking for a way to script it since I have 12 desktops that, now since I'm working remotely, I have to change twice a day.

Comment: "working remotely"… over what? If you're using Apple's Remote Desktop, your local Space-switching keys override the remote's. I have to have my generic 'Mission control' key set differently to the remotes', then I can call theirs by the default Ctrl/up arrow & pick from there.

Comment: Remotely, just meaning, not at home with my extended keyboard and magic trackpad.

Comment: That makes it even less clear… so, you mean at home you have an additional keyboard & mouse on a laptop… then you need to work without them? That's not really 'remote' it's just 'unplugged'. 'Remote' has the connotation of 'over the interwebz', not just unplugging the keyboard.

Comment: Well, the term has several meanings: "Remote work", according to Wikipedia, is work away from the usual place of work. But yes, working without my usual desktop setup available (ie. keyboard and trackpad). However you wanna slice it.